# Make gcc warn about "jump to label crosses initialization of variable"

Tags: c, gcc

By default, gcc doesn't complain about jumping over variable initializations when compiling .c files, while it does when compiling .cpp files. I want it to complain when compiling c files. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

For example, the code below in .c does not produce any warnings/errors, while in .cpp it will:

```
int main()
{
        goto out;
        int i = 0;
out:
        return 0;
}
```

result:

```
gec@ubuntu:~/work/test/json_test$ gcc test.cpp -o test
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:5:1: error: jump to label ‘out’ [-fpermissive]
 out:
 ^
test.cpp:3:7: note:   from here
  goto out;
       ^
test.cpp:4:6: note:   crosses initialization of ‘int i’
  int i = 0;
      ^
```

Comment: What is `crosses initialization` ?

Comment: @Kamil Cuk  I have update problem describe, thank you

Comment: Note that "crosses" is the verb in that warning (with "jump" being the subject). It's not a "crosses initialization".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `-Wjump-misses-init` option (or `-Werror=jump-misses-init` if you want it to be a hard error):

```
$ gcc -Wjump-misses-init try.c
try.c: In function 'main':
try.c:3:9: warning: jump skips variable initialization [-Wjump-misses-init]
         goto out;
         ^~~~
try.c:5:1: note: label 'out' defined here
 out:
 ^~~
try.c:4:13: note: 'i' declared here
         int i = 0;
             ^
```